# iOS - go to second uiviewcontroller of some tab from another tab

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller, storyboard

I'm developing an iOS 5 app using Storyboard.

I have `UITabBarController` which has 3 tabs. Every tab has its own `UINavigationController`. `UINavigationController` of first tab has one `UITableViewController` which segues to another `UIViewController` etc. `UINavigationController` of second tab has only one `UIViewController`.

What I want to achieve is to navigate to `UIViewController` (second view in `UINavigationController` of first tab) when certain action happens in `UIViewController` of second tab.

I've tried to accomplish this using push segue but then the navigation stack becomes mixed with view controllers of different tabs (the back button in destination view controller points to view controller of another tab).

So I want to know what is the "correct way" to accomplish this kind of transition between view controllers of different tabs.

Any help would be very appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use notifications as the first viewController of the first tab might not even be loaded.

So one way you could do it is save a preference (nsuserdefaults perhaps), then switch the tab to the first one, and in the first viewController of the first tab check this preference in viewDidAppear or viewWillAppear, and if it's set then reset the preference (for next time) and auto navigate (push) to the second viewController.

```
BOOL shouldAutoPush=YES;
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] shouldAutoPush forKey:@"shouldAutoPush"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize]; 
[self.tabBarController setSelectedIndex:0];

-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
     if ( [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"shouldAutoPush"] ) {
        BOOL shouldAutoPush=NO;
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] shouldAutoPush forKey:@"shouldAutoPush"];
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize]; 
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:secondViewController animated:YES];                
     }
}
```

Comment: Great! It solves my problem, many thanks! I have one more question.. how should I set some data in destination view controller using this approach. My opinion is that saving custom object in user defaults is not a good idea. Or am I wrong?

Comment: If you have a separate model class for your data you could set one or more properties there? or if a simple app, store the data in the appDelegate maybe. In fact you could also store the above preference in either of those to avoid nsuserdefaults.

Comment: ok. I will probably use some singleton class to store my custom object. Thanks for help!