# complicated Transation in ViewControllers from different UINavigationController in UITabBarController

Tags: ios, objective-c

UITabBarController
|
+- UINavigationController1
|    |
|    +- UIViewController11
|    |
|    +- UIViewController12（Back Button Named “BackBtn” ）
+- UINavigationController2
    |
    +- UIViewController21
    |
    +- UIViewController22（Button Named “BtnB”）

- (a)In UIViewController22 there is a button named “BtnB”,when i touch it the screen will show myViewController12 and the animation like UIViewController22 PushViewTo UIViewController12;
- (b)after (a),I touch the BackBtn(In UIViewController12),the screen will show UIViewController11 and the animation like UIViewController12 pop to UIViewController11.
- Q:With the following page we can achieve it:
  [iOS - go to second uiviewcontroller of some tab from another tab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12560825/ios-go-to-second-uiviewcontroller-of-some-tab-from-another-tab)
  But someone can achieve it more elegant?

Answer (score 0):

I solve it.
In myViewController12， i set the BackBtn's action method as the following code ：

```html
-(IBAction)backAction:(id)sender
{
        self.tabBarController.selectedIndex = 0;
        CATransition* transition = [CATransition animation];
        [transition setDuration:0.3];
        transition.type = kCATransitionPush;
        transition.subtype = kCATransitionFromLeft;
        [transition setFillMode:kCAFillModeBoth];
        [transition setTimingFunction:[CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut]];
        [self.tabBarController.view.layer addAnimation:transition forKey:kCATransition];
        [self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:NO];
}
```